# Can't generate documentation with phpdocumentor 2 with Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, phpdoc

Using Netbeans "Generate PHPDoc", I'm able to generate the structure.xml for my project, but I'm at a lost as to how to get from that XML file to the fully generated phpdoc.

Comment: I found I had not installed the responsive template from phpdocumentor 2. I installed it running the command template:install, but still can't see any html files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to generate my HTML files. I simply needed to activate the XSL extension manually by editing php.ini in WAMP.

I must admit that due to my lack of skills with the command line, it was somehow difficult to follow instructions that are given out on the web.

Comment: In ubuntu: sudo apt-get install php5-xsl